# Setting add-calc-column() values for each browse row?

Tags: progress-4gl

With static browses, on a ROW-DISPLAY I would calculate variables that are columns on a static browse.  However, with ADD-CALC-COLUMN() how do I for each row in a browse go about setting that columns value? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  A bit of sample code illustrating where you are having a problem would help.

Answer (score 0):

A Calculated column cannot really calculate values for you. The name is a bit misleading, to my opinion. You need to use a ROW-DISPLAY trigger to calculate the values yourself and display them in the right column. You may also have to REFRESH the browse in order to activate the trigger on all 'calculated' columns.